# css div structure works on Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have one page with several divs.

Its all working in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not in chrome.

Were is the picture of whats happening.

[image]

The first print is from Google Chrome, the next (the one correct) its from mozzila but its equal to IE.

The red is the parent Div and got this CSS:

```
#full-size{
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    top:5px;
    position:relative; 
    padding: 1px 220px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Then we have the three others, the left and right ones are fized size, the middle one is always adapting with space available.

The css of those three:

```
#left-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative; 
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    background-color:#222;  
    margin-left: -200px;
    float:left;
}
#center-content {
    height:99%;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;  
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    background-color:#222;
}
#right-content {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    float:right;
    position:static; 
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    background-color:#222;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
```

If i change the width from the middle one to less, say 99.7%, the divs stay all in place, but the middle one doesnt stay with the same distance from the border in both sides, not centralized.

If i change, say, from 99.7% to 99.8% the div stays in the bottom. But what i need is 100% for the responsive theme, 100% works in Firefox and IE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probleme comes from white-space from HTML (center displayed as inline-block) and  `font-size`/`letter-spacing` probably dealed different in Chrome.

So , erase those hite-space from html [like](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ipblv):

```
<div id="full-size"><div id="left-content">
    left
  </div><div id="center-content">
    Center
  </div><div id="right-content">
    right
  </div></div>
```

or reset font-size  [like](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ofFsr) :

```
#full-size{
  font-size:0;
}
#full-size > * {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

Best is to get rid of white-space within HTML and not use a css trick or reset.

If you use `display:table` / `table-cell` and `border-spacing`, you have not too worry anymore and you can drop floatting and or `inline-block` methods. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwuIj

Comment: Yeap, that was it. Went with the option of eliminating white spaces, not so organized HTML but good enough, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML put center container after other containers.
Like this:

```
<div id="left-content">
<p>left</p>
</div>

<div id="right-content">
<p>right</p>
</div>

<div id="center-content">
<p>center</p>
</div>
```